# Are Node.js Buffers as JSON a portable storage format?

Tags: node.js, encoding, buffer, portability

If I create  Node.js Buffer containing the bytes of a binary file like a jpg -image, convert it to JSON, can I transport binary content in this way to other machines and have the images viewable on those other machines too?

In other words can I fill a Buffer on one machine with bytes of an image-file, and transport the buffer as JSON to another machine, then restore the image there by simply writing the same buffer to a file with the same name?

Would it work between platforms say Linux Windows and Mac? Does "endiannes" become an issue?

Would TypedArrays be a better solution?

Comment: If it's just an "image" such as a JPG as stated, then diffrerent OS implementations and processor architectures do not care about such things. The worry would be executable content, where it *does* make a difference. As noted, the simplest solution is generally just to send the file, and common transfer protocols handle the how level stuff like byte order for you. For more complex data structures, then a standardized binary format in network byte order is generally preferred.

Answer (score 2):

JSON isn't useful for transferring binary data... at least, not efficiently.  You would have to base64-encode the data before putting it in JSON, which increases its size by 33% and adds an extra layer of processing on each end.

There is another standard serialization format you can use called [CBOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBOR).  It's binary in nature and supports a byte string.  There are libraries for many languages.

Comment: Thanks for the link on CBOR. What if efficiency is not a concern?  Say I need to do it just for a few small images, occasionally? My concern is more portability of the images and other binary content, than efficiency

Comment: @PanuLogic The best thing to do is just to send the file itself.  If you can't do that and must send some sort of structured data, CBOR is incredibly well supported.  It's been standardized for years (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7049), and Wikipedia lists many implementations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBOR#Implementations).